# which language can cast an array to an object?

Tags: php, language-agnostic

I would like to ask if (other than PHP) there is a language that can `cast` a simple array to its object.

In PHP you can do:

```
$obj = (object) $array;

echo $obj->key1;
```

Is there any equivalent in other language? (java,c# etc)

Comment: does this question have any practical purpose?

Comment: Why? You are basically asking "Can other languages degrade semantic value for an identifier". AFAIK most other languages have similar constructs, Java, C# (similar syntax) c++ (void*), Javascript etc.

Comment: @captain: didn't know about taht post an aswer i will pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most other languages have similar constructs.

- Java + C# does this with similar syntax
- In C++ it would be similar to casting to a (void*)
- Javascript would regard an array as any other kind of object.

Comment: Let's leave out C because it doesn't have object :)

Comment: In this context I think `structs` could well be regarded as an object. c++ doesn't have an object type either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the critical point here is not the cast but rather the fact that afterwards, array keys are accessed as if they were regular members of the object.

In many languages, arrays (maps) *are* objects, but they don't expose array keys as fields because arrays are dynamic in nature, but in static languages object fields are fixed. *This means Java and C# don't have a comparable feature* - they do treat arrays as objects, and they do have casts to do that, but they won't give you the same semantics.

So the remaining candidates are dynamic languages such as Python or Javascript. Of those, none which I know of has a construct that would resemble PHPs typecast in detail. It would be possible to write helper functions to convert from arrays/dictionaries to objects in both languages I mentioned.

**Personal statement:** I do think that this is a rather questionable *feature* in PHP.